# Inserting string into MySQL BLOB using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I am converting my PHP code from MySQLI to PDO.

I have two functions that store and retrieve records that have BLOBS.

For storage, I have a desktop app that captures thumbprint image from a scanner, encodes it to string and calls a PHP URL.

In MYSQLI, the (abbreviated) code is:

```
$sql = 'insert into employees (emp_id, thumbprint) values(?,?);';
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sb", $emp_id, null);
$stmt->send_long_data(1, $thumb_data);
$stmt->execute();
```

The examples that I found for storing and retrieving BLOBs do so using files. I suppose I could save the data to a file, reopen it and pass the filepointer to the PDO's bind_param's method, but that seems a roundabout way of doing things and would increase execution time.

How do I store this string var directly?

Comment: Just check [the examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples). You don't need to do anything differently depending on parameter type.

Comment: Did you try to follow the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)?

Comment: Yes, read them. They mention $fp = fopen(...) and then passing $fp into bind_param. Although, one comment mentions that the file can be read into a variable and passed also. Shall try it and see what happens.

Comment: Dedicated CLOB methods are an optimisation to handle large stuff which would otherwise be stored in memory. Try the basics first, enhance later.